# How to get the average of ONE specific column in a 2D array?

Tags: java

The user enters the values into the array then I'd want to get the average of any specific column.

This is the code below:

```
public class Test2DProcess {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        int[][] gradesArray = new int [4][3];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
                System.out.println("Enter grade: ");
                gradesArray [i][j] = input.nextInt();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say I want to sum up the values in the first column of this array then get the average...this would mean the values in positions (0,0)...(1,0)...(2,0)...(3,0) and (4,0) of the array. How would I go about doing so?

Comment: Iterate over elements you want, calculate their sum, divide sum by amount of elements. Assuming indexes are in form `[row, col]` to iterate over specific `row` you need `[row, i]` where `i` will be chancing.

Comment: Make an attempt, show us what you did, why it didn't work:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I got it to work using what mustafacil recommended below: 
It's a long program but this is the segment of the code I did:

    public double getAv (){
    int sumFirst = grades [0][0];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        }
        sumFirst += grades[i][0];
     }
     double averageFirst = (double)sumFirst/4; 
     return (double) averageFirst;
     }

Answer (score 1):

The same way can be useful, don't forget **gradesArray** is a [4][3] grid, so there is no (4,0) element

```
int incremental =0;
double ave = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    incremental += gradesArray[0][i];
}
```

and then

```
 ave = incremental / 4.0;
```

Comment: Ok so let's say I want the average of each individual column stored in a variable to be printed later.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: the average of each individual column stored in a variable to be printed later. 
in your code you must calculate the sum in first for loop. Here is:

```
int[][] gradesArray = new int[4][3];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sumFirst = 0;
    int sumSecond = 0;
    int sumThird = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            System.out.println("Enter grade: ");
            gradesArray[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        }

        sumFirst += gradesArray[i][0];
        sumSecond += gradesArray[i][1];
        sumThird += gradesArray[i][2];

    }

    double averageFirst = (double)sumFirst/4;
    double averageSecond = (double)sumSecond/4;
    double averageThird = (double)sumThird/4;
```

Comment: Ok so let's say I want the average of each individual column stored in a variable to be printed later.